# Errors risen on std::find over a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, iteration, std

In this function I would like to search 'vertex' in the vector queue.

```
bool PriorityQueue::contains(VertexPriority vertex) const {
     return (std::find(queue.begin(), queue.end(), vertex) != queue.end());
}
```

The vector queue is an instance of this object:

```
std::vector<VertexPriority> queue;
```

And my operator overloading is this:

```
bool operator==(const VertexPriority& v){ return (v.vertex == vertex); }
```

How can I solve this error?

The errors risen are the next ones, and at the beginning of every error there is the following path:

> C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\stl_algo.h
>
> In function `_RandomAccessIterator std::find(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, _Tp = VertexPriority]':
>
> instantiated from `_InputIterator std::find(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const _Tp&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, _Tp = VertexPriority]'
>
> passing `const VertexPriority' as`this' argument of `bool VertexPriority::operator==(const VertexPriority&)' discards qualifiers

Comment: `no match for 'operator=='`  Did you implement it in `VertexPriority`>

Comment: Are you finding a vertex in an edge list?!

Comment: no sorry, I wrote wrong the text of this question, now I'll edit

Comment: I implemented the operator overloading just now and edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the operator const:

```
bool operator==(const VertexPriority& v) const 
{ 
    return (v.vertex == vertex); 
}
```

Note that this makes the member function `const` itself, which enables the compiler to invoke it on a `const` object of `VertexPriority` type.

This is actually precisely what the compiler sais:

```
passing const VertexPriority' as this' argument of `bool VertexPriority::operator==(const VertexPriority&)' discards qualifiers
```

The `VertexPriority` object that is const, is being passed as the *implicit `this`argument* to member functions.